# Deduce template argument from std::function call signature

Tags: c++, templates, std-function, template-argument-deduction

Consider this template function:

```
template<typename ReturnT>
ReturnT foo(const std::function<ReturnT ()>& fun)
{
    return fun();
}
```

Why isn't it possible for the compiler to deduce `ReturnT` from the passed call signature?

```
bool bar() { /* ... */ }

foo<bool>(bar); // works
foo(bar); // error: no matching function call
```

Comment: An answer to [one of my previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625526/check-at-compile-time-if-template-argument-is-void) allows this sort of syntax. I hope that helps. It's specialized in case the return type is void too.

Comment: @chris Thanks for the hint - I'll try to understand it :)

Comment: N.B. very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7608741/981959 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9242234/981959, but I think the answers here are clearer for this specific question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::function<bool()> bar;

foo(bar); // works just fine
```

C++ can't deduce the return type from your function `bar` because it would have to know the type before it could find all the constructors that take your function pointer.

For example, who's to say that `std::function<std::string()>` doesn't have a constructor taking a `bool (*)()`?

Answer (score 17):

A function pointer of type `bool (*)()` can be converted to `std::function<bool()>` but is not the same type, so a conversion is needed.  Before the compiler can check whether that conversion is possible it needs to deduce `ReturnT` as `bool`, but to do that it needs to already know that `std::function<bool()>` is a possible conversion, which isn't possible until it deduces `ReturnT` ... see the problem?

Also, consider that `bool(*)()` could also be converted to `std::function<void()>` or `std::function<int()>` ... which should be deduced?

Consider this simplification:

```
template<typename T>
  struct function
  {
    template<typename U>
      function(U) { }
  };

template<typename T>
  void foo(function<T>)
  { }

int main()
{
    foo(1);
}
```

How can the compiler know whether you wanted to create `function<int>` or `function<char>` or `function<void>` when they can all be constructed from an `int`?

Answer (score 1):

The function `bar` is of type `bool (*)()` or so, that is: a normal pre-C++11 function type. I'm not that confident in C++11, but I guess the compiler does not see the connection between `bool (*)()` and `const std::function<ReturnT()>&`, even when the first can be implicitly converted into the second for `ReturnT = bool`.

Comment: Actually, no matter how the conversion proceeds, the definition of std::function is: `template<class R, class... Args>
class function<R(Args...)>` where `R` is known to be `bool` … therefore `ReturnT` should be deducable for `foo`, right?

Comment: @Karl, but `std::function` has a constructor taking _any_ type, so `bool(*)()` could also be converted to `std::function<void()>` or other types - there isn't a single, unique conversion sequence that means only a single `std::function` specialization can be deduced

Comment: @JonathanWakely Okay, think I see it now. Thanks for helping :-)