# No matching function error when passing lambda function as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, type-conversion, callable-object

I have a list of numbers.

I am trying to filter the list and only keep the positive numbers.

I am trying to do it by passing a lambda as an argument.

I wonder why I get function mismatch error.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> keep(
        const std::vector<T> &original,
        std::function<bool(const T&)> useful)
{
    std::vector<T> out;
    for(T item:original)
    {
        if(useful(item))
            out.push_back(item);
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a={4,6,2,-5,3,-8,13,-11,27};
    a=keep(a,[](const int& x)->bool{return x>0;});
    for(int y:a)
    {
        std::cout<<y<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘keep(std::vector<int>&, main()::<lambda(const int&)>)’
     a=keep(a,[](const int& x)->bool{return x>0;});
                                                 ^
```

Comment: You can use the tandard library algorithm [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to do this much more easily: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99cdc73f48d19ba7

Comment: The code in the error message doesn't match your code.

Comment: what compiler you use?

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks, fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++11 Template function that takes a std::function which depends of template parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608741/c11-template-function-that-takes-a-stdfunction-which-depends-of-template-par)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change the function `keep` to

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
std::vector<T> keep(const std::vector<T> &original,
                    Func useful)
{
    // code as usual
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/599d389cfb7b1b8b).

This works with an argument to `useful` being any one of these:

- lambda
- `std::function`
- [functor](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#functor-vs-functionoid)
- function pointer

From [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> The lambda expression constructs an unnamed prvalue temporary object of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate type, known as closure type.

This means that two lambdas with the same code, would generate two different typed objects.

```
auto f1 = [](int) { return true; };
auto f2 = [](int) { return false; };
f2 = f1;                               // error: no viable '='
```

However, both of these are implicitly convert-able to the corresponding `std::function` types:

```
std::function<bool(int)> fn = f1;
fn = f2;
```

But then why doesn't it work in your case? This is because of template type deduction. Changing `keep` to

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> keep(const std::vector<T> &original,
                    std::function<bool(const int &)> useful)
// no type deduction for std::function's template, explicitly mentioned
```

will make your example compile without any cast at the caller site.

However, trying to match it against `std::function<T>` won't work since template type deduction doesn't consider any conversion. Template argument deduction looks for exact type matches. Implicit conversions don't matter at this stage. You've to explicitly cast it to a matching `std::function` as *Atomic_alarm* comments. Like Joseph says in [How to convert a lambda to an std::function using templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13358672/183120):

> Template type deduction tries to match the type of your lambda function to the `std::function<T>` which it just can't do in this case - these types are not the same. Template type deduction doesn't consider conversions between types.

While in the alternative solution what happens is something like this:

```
auto f = [](int i) { return (i >= 0); }
```

The type of `f` here is not `std::function` but some unnamed type deduced like it would for the template parameter `Func` above.

If you still want to do it the `std::function` way, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7609835/183120) which does it with an additional template indirection. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11103829/183120) and [this post](http://meh.schizofreni.co/programming/magic/2013/01/23/function-pointer-from-lambda.html) for related details.

Comment: Thank you. Still I am wondering what is wrong with my code? Where did I do a mistake?

Comment: @ar2015, lambda expression has its own type, so cast  explicitly, or use a template. IDEone: http://ideone.com/r2gYTh

Comment: @ar2015 The detailed reason is now in the updated answer.