# How to use std::function with a template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Why does this not work (in C++11) and how can I fix it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
int apply(string x, const function<int(T)>& fn)
{
    T t = { x };
    return fn(t);
}

struct S {
    string data;
};

int process_s(const S& s)
{
    return s.data.size();
}

int main()
{
    cout << apply("abc", process_s);
}
```

The error is

```
prog.cc:21:8: error: no matching function for call to 'apply'
        cout<<apply("abc", process_s);
              ^~~~~
prog.cc:7:5: note: candidate template ignored: 
  could not match 'function<int (type-parameter-0-0)>'
  against 'int (const S &)'
int apply(string x, const function<int(T)>& fn) {
    ^
1 error generated.
```

I tried the approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7609835), but it doesn't work either:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct id {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
using nondeduced = typename id<T>::type;

template <typename T>
int apply(string x, const function<nondeduced<int(T)> >& fn)
{
    T t = { x };
    return fn(t);
}

struct S {
    string data;
};

int process_s(const S& s)
{
    return s.data.size();
}

int main()
{
    cout << apply("abc", process_s);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second approach only works when there's another way to deduce `T`. Your use case has no other function parameter which can be used for that deduction.

The deduction fails in your original attempt because a function pointer/reference (`process_s`) is not a `std::function`. Implicit conversion won't count, it has to be an object whose type is a `std::function` instantiation for the deduction to succeed.

Assuming there's no option to add any more parameters to the function, you are left with two options:

1. Specify the template argument explicitly, as in `apply<S>(...)`.
2. Create a `std::function` object and pass it to your **first** attempt, as the second function argument.

The second choice can be less ugly in C++17 since there are now [deduction guides](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides) available. So the invocation can in fact become `apply("abc", std::function{process_s});`

Comment: Ah thank you! Is there any improvement for this use case in C++17/20? Or is there an inherent problem with type deduction here that cannot be solved without a major type system redesign?

Comment: @max - It's not a problem really. The deduction rules as specified keep the system sane and prevent it from being intractable. I'll add a note about C++17, if that's an option.

Comment: @max Your problem is not only about deduction. Suppose you have a functor with 2 similar operators defined. Even with implicit conversion, how can compiler chose which one to use ?

Comment: Is it also a problem that he's passing a string literal to a non const std::string parameter in the first example? At least on my compiler that seems to be what stops it from working after I've fixed up the std::function business.

Comment: @Zebrafish - It shouldn't be. That parameter is a value.

Comment: @liliscent I didn't quite understand your comment; what does _functor_ and _operator_ refer to? Or maybe you could post a rough code snippet as an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As @StoryTeller states, an implicit conversion does not count.

The other option that can be considered is, giving up on using `std::function`.
Then it will put you in the right place to start compiling at:

```
template <typename T>
int apply(string x, int(&fn)(T))
{
    T t = { x };
    return fn(t);
}
```

Not to mention that you can avoid the overhead of `std::function` as well.

Comment: But that would prevent me from passing lambdas into the `fn` argument, wouldn't it?

Comment: @max, Yes, but `std::function` is not the only option that takes lambdas.
Just declare a template parameter `Func` to accept lambdas, which can be more efficient.

Comment: Yea, I ended up declaring `template <typename Func>` instead of the whole business with `std::function`. I agree that the additional type safety of specifying that `Func` is actually a callable with a certain signature isn't worth the required complexity.